# Web Driver - How to override user-agent for Microsoft edge

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

According to [Web driver IO specification](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio) , I can set the browser's the user-agent for chrome as below:

```
desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
         args: ['user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53']
    }
}
```

However, I could not find a way to override for Microsoft Edge using `desiredCapabilities` config in Webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information available on the official EdgeDriver page, I do not think MS Edge provides an option to change user agent : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver#w3c-webdriver

Also, here is the java doc for EdgeOptions : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeOptions.html which has a list of support EdgeOptions

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for PHP**

```
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(['--user-agent=' . $userAgent]);

$seleniumServerCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities::microsoftEdge();
$seleniumServerCapabilities->setCapability('ms:edgeOptions', $options);
```

For more intel checkout the source code of the Webdriver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeOptions.java

Answer (score -2):

A quick google search gave me this :

**For Desktop :** 
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; <64-bit tags>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>`

**For Mobile :**
`Mozilla/5.0 (WM 10.0; Android <Android Version>; <Device Manufacturer>; <Device Model>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>`

[More Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh869301(v=vs.85))

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand my question.

I am aware of your given string.

But I want to know how does webdriver support it as a part of its `desiredCapabilities` configuration.